# Modify other page's content from other page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 webpages and both of them in html:

- index.html
- setting.html

They are both linked to each other but here is the thing

index is front end for users, when client enter to setting area webpage have options.

First option:

> *"Don't want to see the setting button?"*

***Buttons***

> "Yes" (Removes the setting button)
>
> "No" (Nothing changes)

and the second option:

> *"Which type of clock did you want?"*

***Dropdown***

> Default
>
> AM/PM
>
> Water
>
> Reversed
>
> Others...

When client choose an option javascript or else can should modify the other page?
If you want it I can send pages with codepen

Comment: Are you sure you want to build such a system without a proper backend? It would be easy to solve this using PHP. Additionally, why not use cookies to store the settings?

Comment: Do you want the settings one user (admin?) makes to be reflected for _all_ users that view this page in their browser afterwards? Then you need a server-side solution to begin with, you can not handle _that_ on the client side only.

Comment: You can use event bus in javascript https://medium.com/@soffritti.pierfrancesco/create-a-simple-event-bus-in-javascript-8aa0370b3969

Comment: save the choice in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) then on the second page you can just check localStorage for the var and use the correct clock accordingly or the default clock if there is no value saved

Comment: i am with @NicoHaase here, but it doesnt need to be php, any serverside script language would do the trick

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53430870/edit) and then `[<>]` the snippet editor. Then you can post the html and the script you tried here

Comment: Also do not ask a negative question. `[X] Show setting button`

Comment: I don't really know the php, i can understand the code but cant write it, so if it can be with html or javascript it could be best otherwise someone need to write the code for me to implement to my code. I tried to use localstore but can't handle it but i will give it a try again thank you. Of couse this options for client not for admin so it should be from client side. I can change the question when i handle this :)